# code scroll to next row in table view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So in my project there is a tableview with each row populated with an image from parse. i was hoping to disable user scroll and have a button scroll down to the next row instead. is this possible?

Figured it out

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
let view = button.superview!
let cell = view.superview as! <cellname>

let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

let row = indexPath?.row

tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row!+1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I have made a sample project on git
https://github.com/hammyhamza/StackOverflow

Comment: im populating the tableview with cellforrowandindexpath so im trying to figure out how to add in [indexPath.row] so it properly goes to the next row after the current. everything ive done it refers to the current row as the first so the button always goes to the second row

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the function scrollToRowAtIndexPath from UITableView to programmatically scroll the table view.

Comment: i got tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: <#Int#>, inSection: <#Int#>), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false) but i dont know what to put for nsindexpath

Comment: assuming you have only 1 section in your table view, your NSIndexPath should be NSIndexPath(forRow:0,inSection:0) for the first row, NSIndexPath(forRow:1,inSection:0) for the second row and so on.

Comment: that only works once, it wont go to the third fourth fifth row

Answer (score 0):

Set the property scrollEnabled to NO.because UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. then you can control the scroll use your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath like so:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

for indexPath you need to use the NSIndexPath class like so:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowYouDesire inSection:sectionYouDesire];
```

Comment: is there a way to do current row + 1? cuz what i haen ow is tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false) and it goes to the second row but now third and fourth fifth

Comment: @gooberboobbutt just create a global variable set it to 1 and just keep adding 1 to it everytime you want to scroll to the next row

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
let view = button.superview!
let cell = view.superview as! <cellname>

let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

let row = indexPath?.row

tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row!+1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8:

```
let mylist = MessageList //your class array

tableView1.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: (mylist?.count)!-1, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: How to scroll table programmatically at the bottom like in messaging? sorry,.. it seems my answer is right, the question is wrong.. what is happening to me... forgive me.., i am terribly out of my mind..

Comment: don't worry it's ok.